# a microcontoller pin stuck permanently at 0

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, stm32f3

Is it possible in general to have a pin of any uC stuck at 0, including when the power is off? Particularly I'm interested in stm32f3

[image]

Comment: What is "power is off" supposed to mean? A fully floating MCU won't be at 0V.

Comment: What do you mean by "stack at"? That term is normally used for a hardware failure situation.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I meant that you have a uC soldered on a PCB and you measure with a VOM for short circuit between a pin, which is not normally grounded, and the GND and you measure no resistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, even likely.

Most pins have overvoltage protection circuitry on them to keep small capacitive discharges from damaging the chip.  Sometimes the circuitry is more elaborate, but often there are simply reverse diodes to power and ground.

This means that when the power voltage is 0, the protection diode of a pin will conduct if the pin voltage would otherwise exceed the diode turnon voltage, around 600 mv.  Since that is a logic low level for just about any digital input, pins of unpowered micocontrollers on the same ground will read as low.

In general it is not good to allow too much current to flow thru the protection diodes.  If the diodes are beefy enough, then you can sometimes power up or partially power up the micro by forcing a I/O pin high.  However, expect it to act flaky.  Power current won't be flowing thru all the intended paths, and the power voltage will be one diode drop below whatever you are holding the pin at.  This also raises the whole power net the micro is connected to, which can have other unexpected consequences.  If the power net draws too much current, the diode will blow out.  Now the pin will be well above the power voltage of the micro, which probably damages a few more things in the micro.

Another issue is SCR latchup when real power is applied normally.  Due to how the chip is constructed and how the substrate is biased, current flowing into a pin while power is coming up can cause a sortof SCR latching effect.  This will draw lots more than the usual current of the micro, which can damage the micro, the power supply, or both.

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail I have to make some guesses. When the power is on and you are expecting a logical 1 but are measuring a logical 0, here are some typical errors:

- Forgetting to configure the pin as an Output.
- For the ARM architecture: Forgetting to enable the pin to function as GPIO.
- For the ARM architecture: Forgetting to enable clocks to the port.
- Improper voltages one of the power rails (Some fancy micros have multiple rails/internal regulator/etc. Be sure to read the data and verify that all voltages are square with a meter).
- The pin or entire microcontroller have been damaged.
- Make sure the code is actually running (set a breakpoint in main and check with a debugger).

When power is off: The voltage (measured to the part's ground) is floating (very high impedance) so will likely read zero with a meter. This is the expected behavior

Answer (score 1):

If it is apparently connected to Vss with power off and it is a GPIO then it is probably damaged and internally shorted. You will probably notice an increase in supply current if you try to drive it high with power on.

Comment: And how it can be internally shorted?

Comment: Too much current can melt an output transistor or protection diode so it loses its ability to block current and becomes a short. That could be a result of ESD or a momentary short to higher voltage than Vcc, including applying a voltage to an input or output when Vcc=0.